# FirebaseAuth の createUser について

Tags: swift, ios, firebase

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: address, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self.showAlert(msg: error.localizedDescription)
                return           
            } else {
                let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
                changeRequest?.displayName = self.displaynameTextField.text
                changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: nil)
```

現在、このような形でユーザーを作成しています。

引数addressとpasswordにはtextFieldに入れられた値を代入しています。
addressとpasswordが空であったり、不正なメールアドレスを入れるとエラーメッセージが出て
ユーザーは作成されません。

今、悩んでいるのは
それとは別にもう一つdisplayNameのためのtextFieldを用意して
それが空だとエラーメッセージを出して、ユーザーを作成しないという処理を行いたいのですが
エラーメッセージは出せても、それでもdisplayNameが無いままユーザーは作成されてしまいます。

textFieldが空だとcreateUserしないという処理はどのように行えばよいでしょうか。

Comment: Firebaseは使ったことがないんですが、`displayName`はFirebase的に必須属性ではない上、「ユーザ作成」「ユーザ属性の変更」は独立した処理として実行されています。従って「textFieldが空だと」掲載されたコードを呼び出さない条件判定を入れるしかないだろうと思います。他にもちょっと気になる部分はあるんですが、エラー処理も含めてちゃんと動いてるんなら問題ないんだろうと思います。実はそこもちょっとおかしいということがあればコメントしてください。

Comment: コメント頂いた通り、条件判定で対処することにしました。おかしいところあるかと思いますがなんとか動いています笑。ありがとうございました！

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。落ち着いてからで構いませんので、自己回答のほうもよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOPerさんのコメントのおかけで解決致しました。

自分が追加したテキストフィールドが空だと、createUserをキャンセルするという処理は出来ないようなので
まず第一にテキストフィールドが空かどうか確認し、条件判定で空だとcreateUserを呼び出さないという風に対処しました。

OOPerさん、ありがとうございました！